# How to customize tooltip on mouse hover of a polar area chart of Angular Charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I have a polar area chart built with Angular Chart, as it follows:

[image: Polar area chart]

I need to customize what's written in the tooltip mouse hover (Right now it shows [label: value], or [MBA010: 98.69], as in the image), or remove that option completely.

I have tried applying the options as shown in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2yZf5QtRVnWFNBwrPSJQ?p=preview), supplied by a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27590397/how-to-change-tooltip-on-angular-chart-js):

```
// Controller
$scope.chart_options = {
  tooltipTemplate: function(label) {
    return label.label + ':' + label.value;
  }
};

<!-- View -->
<canvas class="chart chart-polar-area" 
               chart-data="module.data" 
               chart-labels="module.labels" 
               chart-options="chart_options"></canvas>
```

But these options don't work on the polar area chart, although it works on all the other chart types.

How can I customize, or remove, tooltips on mouse hover for this particular chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Tooltip Callbacks](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) for label, to customize tooltips of a polar-area chart.

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['chart.js']);

app.controller("PolarAreaCtrl", function($scope) {
   $scope.labels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun'];
   $scope.data = [
      [3, 2, 5, 1, 4, 2]
   ];
   $scope.options = {
      legend: false,
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
               //return text to render for an individual item in the tooltip
               return 'This is a custom tooltip';
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.chartjs/latest/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PolarAreaCtrl">
   <canvas id="polarArea" class="chart chart-polarArea" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. `callbacks: {}` is what was missing to get it to work.
P.S.: GRUNT itself answered my question? wow...